What does the switch keyword do?
I am familiar with switch case statements, but not so with switch statement. Is it a new feature added to dart? What does it really do? Here is the code snippet.
    Map.fromEntries(
        inputMap.entries.map(
          (e) {
           
            return MapEntry(
                e.key,
                switch (e.value) {
                  DateTime t => toJsonDateTime(t),
                  Duration d => toJsonDuration(d),
                  Enum t => t.name,
                  _ => e.value,
                });
          },
        ),
      ),


As Flutter uses Dart, you can look this up in the reference docs of Dart for switch expressions

Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

They just modified the pattern of switch statement explained in this article.
It works with sdk version >= 3.0.0.
In your code, it works exactly like before e.g. if e.value is a DateTime object, this case executes and calls the toJsonDateTime function and so on.
The '_' (underscore) acts as a default handler and is optional.

I think an important point to mention is that it not only executes the statement for that case but also returns the value. In the example given it is using the return value of the switch expression as an argument to MapEntry. You can also use it like var x = switch (...) {...}
